# Get the top patent countries, codes in a BQ public dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to use an analytic function to get the top 2 countries with patent applications, and within those top 2 countries, get the top 2 application kinds. For example, the answer will look something like this:

```
country  -   code 
US           P
US           A
GB           X
GB           P
```

Here is the query I am using to get this:

```
SELECT
  country_code,
  MIN(count_country_code) count_country_code,
  application_kind
FROM (
  WITH
    A AS (
    SELECT
      country_code,
      COUNT(country_code) OVER (PARTITION BY country_code) AS count_country_code,
      application_kind
    FROM
      `patents-public-data.patents.publications`),
    B AS (
    SELECT
      country_code,
      count_country_code,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY count_country_code DESC) AS country_code_num,
      application_kind,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY country_code ORDER BY count_country_code DESC) AS application_kind_num
    FROM
      A)
  SELECT
    country_code,
    count_country_code,
    application_kind
  FROM
    B
  WHERE
    country_code_num <= 2
    AND application_kind_num <= 2) x
GROUP BY
  country_code,
  application_kind
ORDER BY
  count_country_code DESC
```

However, unfortunately, I get a "memory exceeded" error due to the over/order/partition. Here is the message:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 112% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 98% other/unattributed: 2%

How would I go about doing the above query (or other similar queries) without running into these memory errors? This can be tested on the public dataset [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google_patents_public_datasets/google-patents-public-data?filter=solution-type:dataset&q=google%20patents%20public%20datasets&id=2877ec09-debc-41bd-a2d7-df1fd089e4d0).

One crude way to do it (which only works if the fields have a semi-low cardinality), would be to do it as a straightforward aggregation operation and sort the results in-memory outside the DB. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH A AS (
  SELECT country_code
  FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications`
  GROUP BY country_code
  ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
  LIMIT 2
), B AS (
  SELECT
    country_code,
    application_kind,
    COUNT(1) application_kind_count
  FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications`
  WHERE country_code IN (SELECT country_code FROM A)
  GROUP BY country_code, application_kind
), C AS (
  SELECT
    country_code,
    application_kind,
    application_kind_count,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY country_code ORDER BY application_kind_count DESC) AS application_kind_rank
  FROM B
)
SELECT
  country_code,
  application_kind,
  application_kind_count
FROM C
WHERE application_kind_rank <= 2
```

with result

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks for this response. So the approach here is basically to chop off the first level by pre-filtering to those top values and then doing a sub-select.

Comment: i think, this make sense, as otherwise you are "wasting" resources for calculating all the ranks for whatever known to be eliminated from final result anyway